# Change the screen of LCD using button

Tags: c, microcontroller, lcd

I have two buttons first  `mode button`  and second  `set button` connected to the 8051 microcontroller. The mode button changes the LCD screen and the set button blinks the cursor when the individual button is pressed. I am just toggling the mode button so that when the cursor is blinked the mode button performs the function of changing the screen and when the cursor is not blinked it preforms another function. But when the cursor is not blinked it's performing the function but when the cursor is blinked it changes the screen of the LCD but returns back to the initial state without pressing the button again. I want it when the cursor is blinked and the mode button is pressed to change the screen of the LCD and after reaching the last screen return to the initial first screen.

```
typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0
bool blink_enabled = false; 
unsigned char setmode_in = 0;
static unsigned count = 0;

void display_lcd(void){
         switch(key_code){
              case KEY_UP: 
                 if (setmode_in == 0){                               
                    lcd_out(0x01);           //clear the screen of LCD                                                              
                }else{
                    count = (count+1)%3;
                    setmode_in=0;
         switch(count){                         
               case 0:      
                    change_screen1();                    
                    break;  
               case 1:      
                    change_screen2();                    
                    break;
               case 2:    
                    change_screen3();                    
                    break;
               default:  break;
            }
            case KEY_SET:  
               if(blink_enabled == true){                    
                    lcd_out(0x0c);             // cursor off
                    blink_enabled = false;
                    setmode_in = 0;
            } else{             
                    lcd_out(0x0F);            //blink the cursor                                
                    blink_enabled = true;
                    setmode_in = 1; 
            }
                    break;                      
             default: break;    
           }    
             key_code = 0; 
          }
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: The problem appears to be that you have lost track of what is within each scope `{ ... }`. Your outer `switch()` only has a single case `case KEY_UP:`, the remainder is under your `else {` statement (which may be intended) -- that's up to you. Generally, when handling button-press events, you want your code to respond to the button interrupt. The button interrupt simply sets a flag indicating the button was pressed and then the code that handles the button press is conditioned on checking the flag in your main program loop and responding appropriately. Hard to tell with what you have.

Comment: outer `switch`'s `KEY_UP` case missed a `break`